# multiple bundles with browerify and gulp

Tags: javascript, build, bundle, gulp

I can't find any examples using gulp and browerify in order to build multiple bundle.

I just want to do [that](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles) with gulp.

I found this [repo](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle) but I how use it into a gulpfile.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question didn't get much attention because **browserify** is misspelled as **browerify**.

If you are still interested, here is an example gulpfile.js recipe to do exactly the same as the [example in node-browserify docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', ['build-common', 'build-beep', 'build-boop']);

gulp.task('build-common', function () {
  var b = browserify()
    .require('./robot'); // same as -r option

  var stream = b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('common.js')) // the output filename
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/')); // the output directory
  return stream;
});

gulp.task('build-beep', function () {
  var b = browserify('./beep.js')
    .external('./robot.js'); // same as -e option

  var stream = b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('beep.js')) // the output filename
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/')); // the output directory
  return stream;
});

gulp.task('build-boop', function () {
  var b = browserify('./boop.js')
    .external('./robot.js'); // same as -e option

  var stream = b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('boop.js')) // the output filename
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/')); // the output directory
  return stream;
});
```

Of course, this is a little bit verbose but I hope this can help you to get started.

I have written a couple of browserify-related gulp recipes that might be useful: https://github.com/sogko/gulp-recipes